# Is it possible to share sessions across subdomains which are different applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to share sessions across subdomains which are different applications without using Sql Server Session mode? I've implemented this concept with help from this link:

[What options are there for sharing data across subdomains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245947/what-options-are-there-for-sharing-data-across-subdomains#1271463)

However is it possible without Sql Server mode may be using in proc etc?

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273732/how-can-i-share-a-session-across-multiple-subdomains-in-asp-net

Comment: This link uses Sql server itself. I want to see if it is possible without that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this using InProc, each application will have its own memory space.

You could set up a web service to get around the issue, although I find this solution to be more of a hack.

You could alternatively use a key/value store database or some flavour of NoSQL.

A custom session state provider would be a more elegant solution.

[MongoDB ASP.NET Session State Store Provider](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2011/05/mongodb-aspnet-session-state-store.html)